# MySql returning multiple rows from stored procedure / function

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I need to make a stored procedure or function that returns a set of rows. I've noted that in a stored procedure i can `SELECT * FROM table` with success. If i fetch rows in a loop and `SELECT something, something_other FROM table` once per loop execution, I only get one single result.

What I need to do is looping, doing some calculations and returning a rowset. What's the best way to do this? A temporary table? Stored functions?

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you're using a cursor inside the body of the stored procedure to accomplish your looping?

My first advise is: try to do your calculations in a single query without resorting to cursors.  What's the calculation exactly?

If you really do need to use a cursor, then INSERT the results of each loop into a temporary table and then SELECT * from that table when you're done looping.

Answer (score 0):

You can return multiple result sets but only if the client library supports it and the client is expecting it. Some don't, so using them will result in out-of-sequence errors.

You can certainly build a temporary table, select from it and drop it inside the procedure, that would be safe. Another option is to build a UNION select using a prepared SQL statement which returns all the rows you need and execute that. That's a bit messy.